# Cypress: How can we bypass cross origin error in Firefox? (iframes)

Tags: firefox, iframe, cypress

I have two ongoing and long issue with Firefox and Cypress regarding iframes and cross origin errors. This will be the first part of my question, this is for the iframes. My issue is, whenever I try to run my code in Firefox, I am getting this error below and unable to interact with the iframe. I have set the `chromeWebSecurity` to false to be able to do so in Chrome. Do we have the same for Firefox? Maybe a plugin?

[image: error picture]

This is the code to play the video. It works in Chrome but never in Firefox.

```
playVideo(){
    cy.get(createTextPagePO.getYouTubeVideoOnPreview()).then(function($youTubeVideo){
        const youTubeVideo = $youTubeVideo.contents().find(createTextPagePO.getYouTubeRedPlayButton())
        cy.wrap(youTubeVideo)
            .click({force: true})
    })
}
```

I cannot fully disclose the page object code for our application but let's say I tried to embed this iframe code. And I want to click the `Play` button.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3GNOLYNxGfQ" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

What it looks like in our site is:
[image: embedded iframe]

Comment: Since you're asking about iframes, can you show the iframe code (currently hidden in PO)?

Comment: Hi @TesterDick I edited my question and posted the iframe. Thank you!