# Cypress: Is there a counterpart for chromeWebSecurity in Firefox?

Tags: cypress, cross-domain, websecurity

I have test cases in our project that needs to interact with iframes. Some also needs to go outside of the original domain to run. Do we have a counterpart for `chromeWebSecurity` in Firefox? My tests passes in Chrome, Edge and Electron but not in Firefox. Thank you in advance!

Here are my original questions:

1. [Cypress: How can we bypass cross origin error in Firefox? (iframes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73214884/cypress-how-can-we-bypass-cross-origin-error-in-firefox-iframes)
2. [Cypress: How can we bypass cross origin error in Firefox? (cross origin issue, outside cy.origin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73216608/cypress-how-can-we-bypass-cross-origin-error-in-firefox-cross-origin-issue-o)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. There are possibly other workarounds for differences between Chrome and Firefox, but I'm not an export on either post you linked. (The reason for Chrome having this support and Firefox not, is simply that Chrome has been supported by Cypress for much longer than Firefox, and probably Chromium exposing more of it's API than Gecko)

Comment: Thank you @agoff! I tried other workarounds as well but so far nothing has been working. :/ But do you happen to have some links for workarounds? Other than the ones in Cypress documents?